# Can't connect to EC2 in php with ssh2_auth_pubkey_file

Tags: php, ssh, amazon-ec2, pem

I'm trying to connect my EC2 instance with ssh2 php module.

I've obtained the public key from known_hosts file (format: "ssh-rsa XXXX..." putted into "public.txt" file) and i'm using the amazon keypair.pem as private key ("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- XXXX..." in private.pem).

I'm using this php code:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('XXXX.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com', 22, array('hostkey'=>'ssh-rsa'));    
if(!ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(
    $connection,
    'ubuntu',
    'public.txt',
    'private.pem'
))
    die("Auth error");  
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
```

The error i get is:
ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(): Authentication failed for ubuntu using public key: Username/PublicKey combination invalid

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public key in the known_hosts file isn't the public key you need to be using. Rather, you need to be using the public key from authorized_keys.

That said, the fact that libssh2 even requires the public key is stupid. Honestly, I'd recommend you use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation, over libssh2](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/intro.html). eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$ssh = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('private.pem'));
if (!$ssh->login('username', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

print_r($ssh->nlist());
?>
```

Comment: Any idea why ssh2_auth_pubkey_file asks for the public key? And why the public key should be in OpenSSH format?

Comment: @bogdanioan.gabor - the way SSH works is that you send it the username and the public key you want to use to authenticate with. If the server accepts it you'll then need to sign something with the private key such that the server can verify it with the public key. So when libssh2 asks for the public key it's probably because it isn't able to extract the public key from the private key nor is it able to convert the format to the appropriate one.

Comment: @neubert Thanks for your response.